# How do I place multiple searched tweets into string

Tags: python, string, output, tweepy, tweets

I have a program set up so it searches tweets based on the hashtag I give it and I can edit how many tweets to search and display but I can't figure out how to place the searched tweets into a string. this is the code I have so far

```
    while True:
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag).items(2):
                tweet = [status.text]
print tweet
```

when this is run it only outputs 1 tweet when it is set to search 2

Comment: How does your code exit the `while` loop? Is your code properly indented? Assuming your `print` is inside the scope of the `while` loop, it only prints one value because you are overwriting the value of `tweet`, then `print` only gets called with the last value. Try moving the `print` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like there's nothing to break out of the `while` loop. One method that comes to mind is to set a variable to an empty list and then with each tweet, append that to the list.

```
foo = []
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag).items(2):
   tweet = status.text
   foo.append(tweet)
print foo
```

Of course, this will print a list. If you want a string instead, use the string *join()* method. Adjust the last line of code to look like this:

```
bar = ' '.join(foo)
print bar
```